# jQuery mobile slider .refresh() reloading entire page

Tags: jquery, mobile, slider, refresh

I'm using this line of code in my (desktop) JQM website and it does what it's supposed to do with the slider, but it's also refreshing the entire page which is rather annoying.

Any ideas on how I can reset the slider button manually, without using the `.refresh()` method (or how to prevent it from reloading the whole page)?

```
$("#slider1").val("3").refresh();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
$("#slider1").val("3").slider("refresh");
```

For more information read [jQuery Mobile Docs - Slider](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider/methods.html)